# Hilbert-calculus, formal proof

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, formal-proofs

I have to give a formal proof in the Hilbert calculus for

> $(\forall x\,\,\phi)\rightarrow (\forall y\,\, \phi\frac{y}{x})$, if $x$ is free for $y$ in $\phi$ and $y$ is not free  in $\phi$.

Unfortunately I have no idea how this proof could be done.

I would be very grateful, if someone could give a hint, or maybe show an example proof, using the Hilbert-calculus.

Comment: What are your axioms? Have you tried to apply directly the axiom schemes [Q5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_system#Logical_axioms) and [Q6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_system#Logical_axioms) here?

Comment: Excuse me, I do not know where to start. Yes, I have to use the axiom schemes, but I cant really imagine how I have to combine them to get this result.

Answer (score 2):

See :

- Herbert Enderton, [A Mathematical Introduction to Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=dVncCl_EtUkC&pg=PA112) (2nd ed - 2001), page 112 :

1) $\forall x \phi$ --- assumption

2) $\forall x \phi \to \phi^y_x$ --- Ax.2 : $x$ is free for $y$ in $\phi$

3) $\phi^y_x$ --- from 1) and 2) by *modus ponens*

4) $\forall y \phi ^y_x$ --- from 3) by **Generalization Th** [page 117 : $y$ not *free* in $\forall x \phi$]

> 5) $\forall x \phi \to \forall y \phi ^y_x$ --- from 1) and 4) by **Deduction Th** [page 118].